# Using Ontorefine to import data from a Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, graphdb, ontorefine

I am using GraphDD  9.5 Free and I would like to import data from a Postgresql database (version 13 installed on a Windows 64 bits machine). However, after I add the connection settings, even if it looks like I'm connected when I run a simple select query I  don't get any data (it keeps sending requests).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkg62.png)

Comment: The shown request in the tab is not related to the Ontorefne interface. The workbench polls the database to check what's the number of running queries/updates.

Answer (score 0):

GraphDB 9.5 Free has [a new data virtualization feature](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/virtualization.html) that allows you to directly query a PostgreSQL database using an Ontop repository (a virtual SPARQL to SQL translation layer).

From the screenshot it is not fully clear if the issue appears only if you change the parsing settings or the first time you load the data. Please note that OpenRefine loads all data in memory so its scalability is limited to the available RAM.